# Bootstrap tooltip auto placement not working with modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tooltip inside a modal. If the placement is simply `left`, it works but the text is occluded. However with `auto left`, I expected the placement to automatically re-orient but it doesn't show at all.

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktzkedLm/2/) works without `auto` but text is occluded
- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktzkedLm/1/) doesn't work with `auto`

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input id="inp" class="form-control" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#modal').modal()

$('#inp').tooltip({
    'trigger': 'manual', 
    'placement': 'auto left',
    'title': 'Hello there',
    'viewport': 'body'
});

$('#inp').tooltip('show');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like this:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input id="inp" class="form-control" type="text" rel="tooltip" title="test Tool Tip">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#modal').modal()

$('#inp').tooltip();
```

This is working. You just have to add `rel="tooltip"` on your input and add title.

Comment: You missed the placement. Try with `auto left` and see if it works. The `rel` is not a required attribute for tooltip.